# S/MIME with GMail in Browser

Tags: email, encryption, gmail, smime

So I have a S/MIME Certificate at StartSSL now. I can now use it in my Thunderbird on Ubuntu and Windows 7. But how can I configure my Browser(Chrome) to use my certificate(which is already imported into the browser btw) with the Browser Mail Client of GMail? I already can use the Certificate to login at StartSSL

Comment: Any luck? Did you try the suggestions in the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Use Penango, Secure Webmail, with GMail. Firefox and Explorer supported. Use with Chrome is currently under development. Go to download.

You can also try End-To-End for Google Chrome. It's in github.